# How to use vanilla JS Signature Pad with Angular 8 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I am new to Angular, and I am having issues integrating szimek/signature_pad into my application. I have read articles on how to use JavaScript libraries in Angular 2+ apps, and they have worked with other libraries I have tried. However, I cannot get signature_pad to work. I am aware of angular versions of signature pad, however, I am required to use the JavaScript version.

Steps I have taken:

```
npm install --save signature_pad

npm install --save @types/signature_pad

import * as _signaturePad from 'signature_pad';  in app.component.ts
```

`"scripts": ["src/app/js/signature_pad.js"]`    in angular.json

```
<script src="./app/js/signature_pad.js"></script>
```

Every thing I have tried leads to an error. Can someone please help?

Comment: You've told us steps you've taken, but forgot to include the error.  What error are you getting or how you're trying to use the library.  Other than importing it; I assume at some point you need to create an instance and use the classes inside the signature pad somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't too hard for me to get this working in a new Angular project.

You had the first steps right.  Create a new Angular app with the CLI and install signature_pad library:

```
npm install --save signature_pad
```

Note, I did not install the types library, but there is no reason you can't.  I did not have to add this library to the Angular.json because the Angular CLI will include it in the main app automagically from the node_modules once we import it.

Before we jump into the typescript, make sure you have a canvas set up in `app.component.html`. I just deleted all the defaults and added this:

```
<canvas #canvas></canvas>
```

Note that I use the `#canvas` syntax as part of the canvas.  This is so I can access this in code.

Now move to your `app.component.ts` file. I'll go over my changes from top to bottom.

First, import the library, like this:

```
import SignaturePad from 'signature_pad';
```

Then, be sure the class implements the `OnInit` interface.  You'll need an import for this:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
```

And you'll have to add the implements text after the AppComponent class definition:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
```

Now, inside the component class, create an instance variable for the signature pad:

```
  public signaturePad: SignaturePad;
```

Create a ViewChild for the canvas:

```
  @ViewChild('canvas', {static: true }) public canvas: ElementRef;
```

And finally, add an `ngOnInit()` method:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.signaturePad = new SignaturePad(this.canvas.nativeElement);
  }
```

The `ngOnInit()` method initializes the SignaturePad class, [per the instructions in the read me](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) by passing into it the HTML element that will be used for the base.  We get that by introspecting the `nativeElement` on our `ViewChild`.

Once I did this, everything worked fine.

You should be able to easily wrap this library up in an Angular component if you wished, and there are a bunch of APIs in the library I did not use for the purposes of this sample.  You'll need to delve into [the sample from the lib repo](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/tree/master/docs) to see how they do things like change the color, clear, or save the signature.